# Symbols are corrupted when saving a Word docx as pdf

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013, save-as

I have a Word document with some symbols, and I need to save this document as pdf instead of docx to make sure that the format is kept the same (Word 2013)

However, when I save as pdf and open this pdf file, I find that these special symbols are corrupted. **What should I do?** I even tried to do the conversion online and the number of corrupted symbols increased.

***Snapshot of the symbol in Word:***

[image]

***And this is how it looks in pdf when I save as pdf:***

[image]

Comment: Rather than Save as PDF, have you tried the Microsoft Print to PDF option, or other printer drivers, such as in Nitro PDF?

Comment: Thanks, mate. This saved my day :) Kindly write this as answer so others can benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than Save as PDF, try the Microsoft Print to PDF option, or other printer drivers, such as in Nitro PDF.